# Generate directed graph without returning edges in java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, generator

I'm trying to make a directed graph generator to use it in LJF algorithm. The thing is that I have no idea how to avoid the returning edges (eg. if I got 1 -> 2 I don't want to have 2 -> 1). I only made a statement in `if` to avoid edges to the same node (eg. 1 -> 1). Another problem is that my generator sometimes leaves some nodes alone without any edges but I need at least one edge per node. What I want to reach is something similar to BST but there is no rule to have max 2 edges, it can be more.

```
public class Graph {

private final int maxT = 3;
private final int chance = 30;  //chance to connect edges
Map<Task, List<Transmission>> tasks = new HashMap<Task, List<Transmission>>();

public Graph() {

    Random r = new Random();

    int range = r.nextInt(maxT) + 3; // number of nodes
    for(int i = 0; i<range; i++){
        List<Transmission> trans = new ArrayList<Transmission>();
        tasks.put(new Task(i), trans);
    }
    System.out.println("Number of tasks: " + tasks.size());

    for(Task key1 : tasks.keySet()){
        for(Task key2 : tasks.keySet()){
            if(key1 != key2 && r.nextInt(100) < chance)
                tasks.get(key1).add(new Transmission(key1,key2));
        }
    }

}

public void printGraph(){
    System.out.println("Generated graph:\n");
    for(Task key : tasks.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key.getId());
        for(Transmission ts : tasks.get(key)){
            System.out.println("\t" + ts.getT1().getId() + " -> " + ts.getT2().getId());
        }
    }       
}
}
```

====EDIT====

After adding order to iterations:

```
        List<Task> keys = new ArrayList<Task>(tasks.keySet());
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < keys.size(); j++){
            tasks.get(i).add(new Transmission(keys.get(i), keys.get(j)));}
    }
```

I got java.lang.NullPointerException exception on this line:

```
tasks.get(i).add(new Transmission(keys.get(i), keys.get(j)));}
```

I see that my newly added list is full of null elements, I attach then Task class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Task extends Node{

Random r = new Random();
int tstart; // start time
int tend; // end time
int size; 
int deadline; 
public Task(int id) {
    super(id);
    tstart = r.nextInt(5);
    tend = r.nextInt(5);
    size = r.nextInt(10);
    deadline = r.nextInt(8);
}

public int getDeadline() {
    return deadline;
}
public int getTstart() {
    return tstart;
}
public int getTend() {
    return tend;
}
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}
```

}

===EDIT====

Now I got the problem that my generator gives me cycles which I don't want to have. So, I added again chance to make a transmission but sometimes I got free nodes or to seperate graphs.

```
List<Task> keys = new ArrayList<Task>(tasks.keySet());
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < keys.size(); j++){
            if(r.nextInt(100) < chance && tasks.get(keys.get(i)).isEmpty())
                tasks.get(keys.get(i)).add(new Transmission(keys.get(i), keys.get(j)));}
    }
```

Comment: Are you thinking to have a strict tree, or would it be OK if there were two paths from A to B, e.g. 1 -> 2 -> 4 and 1 -> 3 -> 4? Are longer cycles OK, say, 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ->4 -> 1?

Comment: In your NullPointerException line: use `tasks.get(keys.get(i))...` instead of `tasks.get(i)...`.

Comment: @Beethoven yes, it works, obviously idk why i didn't see it. Anyway, do you know how to avoid free nodes in this example?

Comment: @Beethoven because this one gives the cycles so i added, again, chance to make a transmission

Comment: @Buszman You will have to bypass the random, if the transmission list is still empty, like below: `if(tasks.get(keys.get(i)).isEmpty() || r.nextInt(100) < chance)`

Comment: @Beethoven yes, I just did it but now I got the cycles which I don't want to have

Comment: @Buszman Your mistake is the '&&' operator. You have to use '||'. Better solution: Add the first edge outside the inner for loop. This asserts that there always is at least one edge: `for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++) { tasks.get(keys.get(i)).add(new Transmission(keys.get(i), keys.get(i + 1))); for(int j = i + 2; j < keys.size(); j++) { if(r.nextInt(100) < chance) tasks.get(keys.get(i)).add(new Transmission(keys.get(i), keys.get(j))); } }` Sorry for missing line breaks :(

Comment: Added the new solution to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a list of `Transmission`s for each `Task`, you could use a map, indexed by the destination node. Then, you can easily perform a check, whether a backwards-edge already exists. Furthermore, you can add a condition to always generate an edge when the node has none:

```
public class Graph {

    private final int maxT = 3;
    private final int chance = 30;  //chance to connect edges
    Map<Task, Map<Task, Transmission>> tasks = new HashMap<>();

    public Graph() {

        Random r = new Random();

        int range = r.nextInt(maxT) + 3; // number of nodes
        for(int i = 0; i<range; i++){
            Map<Task, Transmission> trans = new HashMap<>();
            tasks.put(new Task(i), trans);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of tasks: " + tasks.size());

        for(Task key1 : tasks.keySet()){
            for(Task key2 : tasks.keySet()){
                if(key1 != key2
                        && !tasks.get(key2).containsKey(key1) // Don't generate an edge, if there already is a reverse edge
                        && (tasks.get(key1).isEmpty() // Always generate an edge, if there is none
                            || r.nextInt(100) < chance))
                {
                    tasks.get(key1).put(key2, new Transmission(key1,key2));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void printGraph(){
        System.out.println("Generated graph:\n");
        for(Task key : tasks.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key.getId());
            for(Transmission ts : tasks.get(key).values()){
                System.out.println("\t" + ts.getT1().getId() + " -> " + ts.getT2().getId());
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

New solution trying to incorporate all requirements discussed in the various comments:

```
public Graph() {

    Random r = new Random();

    int range = r.nextInt(maxT) + 3; // number of nodes
    for(int i = 0; i<range; i++){
        List<Transmission> trans = new ArrayList<Transmission>();
        tasks.put(new Task(i), trans);
    }
    System.out.println("Number of tasks: " + tasks.size());

    List<Task> keys = new ArrayList<Task>(tasks.keySet());
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++) {
        Task task1 = keys.get(i);
        List<Transmission> task1Transmissions = tasks.get(task1);
        task1Transmissions.add(new Transmission(task1, keys.get(i + 1)));
        for(int j = i + 2; j < keys.size(); j++) {
            if(r.nextInt(100) < chance)
                task1Transmissions.add(new Transmission(task1, keys.get(j)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That one seems good but next step for my program is to schedule this tasks on processors and I have no idea how to refer to this second Map

Comment: @Buszman If you need the `Transmission`s from a `Task`, you can use `tasks.get(task).values()`, i.e. get the collection of values (=`Transmission`s) from the inner map. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Your solution is overkill. Do not use unindexed loops.

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't work properly. Should all of these statements be in one IF ?

Comment: You mean `key1 != key2 && !tasks.get(key2).containsKey(key1) && (tasks.get(key1).isEmpty()  || r.nextInt(100) < chance)`? Yes, aren't they in one `if`?

Comment: Yes, they are but in this case, I got eg 2 - > 2 and the returning edges...

Comment: I mean if all of these conditions should be in the same IF: if(key1 != key2 
&& !tasks.get(key2).containsKey(key1) && (tasks.get(key1).isEmpty()) || r.nextInt(100) < chance)

Comment: That is exactly what I intended, too. But this explicitly excludes return-edges and self-pointing edges. I don't see why you get them anyway!?

Comment: @Beethoven thank you very much for your help, this one is really close to what i want to achieve but it generates eg:
 1 -> 4
 4 -> 3
 4 -> 2
 3 -> 0
 0 -> 2
And the 0-> 2 here is unnecessary, i would have rather 4 - > 0 instead of that. This would be graph wchich i need

Comment: @Buszman what is wrong with this output? No cycles, no free nodes.

Comment: @Buszman Why is this wrong/unnecessary? Which are the additional requirements to the algorithm?

Comment: @Beethoven Sorry, my fault. It is okay, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 2):

It is simple to avoid (2 -> 1) edes if you have (1 -> 2). For each edge (x -> y) assume that x < y.

Add ordering to iterations:

```
List<T> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
for (int i = 0; i < keys.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < keys.size(); j++) {
        make new Transmission(keys.get(i), keys.get(j));
    }
}
```

To solve the complete problem you need an alogorithm like this:

1. `N` - set of non visited vertexes. All vertexes at the beginning.
2. `V` - set of visited vertexes. Empty at the beginning.
3. Take random vertex `x` from `N`.
4. Add edge(s) (random vertex from `V` -> `x`) from second iteration.
5. Add `x` to `V` and remove `x` from `N`.
6. Continue to step 3 or quit.

Your graph will be oriented cycles-free.

Comment: Thank you for the algorithm, this one was very helpful to order my thinking!

Comment: Should I create additional List to order iterations?

Comment: If you define a total order for the vertices, wouldn't that imply an acyclic graph? Not sure if this is intended.

Comment: as I mentioned - graph will be oriented cycles-free

Comment: @Sergey Rybalkin Oops, reading carefully till the end is an often underrated virtue :(

Comment: @Beethoven yes this graph should be acyclic, that would be perfect though

Comment: @Buszman Then my above solution won't work, it does not exclude cycles, only direct return-edges. You'll have to implement Sergey's algorithm.

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin Ok, but I have one more question. My compilator throws exception NullPointer on this line: tasks.get(i).add(new Transmission(keys.get(i), keys.get(j))); what should I do?

Comment: How is that possible?  In the very first loop in my class I fill it properly @edit is it because of the values? the list are nulls at the very beginning

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin do you know why the list which I created to add order is full of nulls?

Comment: @Buszman Difficult to tell without seeing any code, can you maybe add it as an edit to your question?

Comment: @Beethoven sure, i just did that

Comment: @Buszman you solved only the problem with "returning" edges. You did not implement the whole algo

Comment: @Buszman Note, ordering prevent **only** from "returning" edges

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin you're right, can you give me an advice, how to arrange this algo in Java?

Comment: @Buszman Try `Set<Vertex>`. `Vertex` could be even an index. `Set` has all the operations you need. And collect `Edges` as `List`. Then form the  adjacency list - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list